# For any parallelotope there exist $n!$ simplexes whose interiors are disjoint and whose union is the parallelotope

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, affine-geometry

> **Definition**
>
> If $x_0,...,x_n$ are $(n+1)$ affinely indipendent point of $\Bbb R^n$ (which means that the vectors $(x_1-x_0),...,(x_n-x_0)$ are linearly independent) then simplex determined by them is the set
> $$
> S:=\Biggl\{x\in\Bbb R^n: x=\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_nv_n, \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\le1\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\alpha_i\ge0\,\,\,\text{for all}\,i\Biggl\}
> $$
> where $v_i:=(x_i-x_0)$ for each $i>0$.
>
> **Definition**
>
> If $x_0,...,x_n$ are $(n+1)$ affinely indipendent point of $\Bbb R^n$ then the parallelotopoe determined by them is the set
> $$
> P:=\Big\{x\in\Bbb R^n:x:=\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_nv_n,\,\alpha_i\in[0,1]\,\text{for each}\,i\Big\}
> $$
> where $v_i:=(x_i-x_0)$ for each $i>0$.

Now if $n=2$ the simplexes and the parallelotopes are respectively triangles and parallelograms. So we observe that if the point $x,\,y$ and $z$ determine a parallelogram then the simplex $S$ generated by $x,\,y$ and $z$ and the simplex $S'$ generated by $y':=y\,z':=z$ and $t':=x+v+w$ where $v:=(y-x)$ and $w:=(z-x)$  determine a partition of the parallelotope generated by $x,\,y$ and $z$ that is
$$
S\cup S'=P\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,S\cap S'=\partial S\cap\partial S'
$$
as we know by the elementary geometry.

So I ask how to generalise this result: in particular if the volume of a simplex and of a parallelotope are respectively given by the formulas
$$
v(S)=\Big|\frac{1}{n!}\det\big[(x_1-x_0),...,(x_n-x_0)\big]\Big|\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,v(P)=\Big|\det\big[(x_1-x_0),...,(x_n-x_0)\big]\Big|
$$
then I imagine that for any parallelotope there exist $n!$ simplexes whose interiors are disjoint and whose union is the parallelotope. Otherwise if the statement is generally false I ask if there exist $n$ simplexes of volume $\frac 1 n$ whose interiors are disjoint and whose unione is the parallelotope. **However I suspect that the proof could be done by induction**.

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: I guess by an affine transformation we can transform $x_0$ to the origin $0$ of $\Bbb R^n$ and for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$  a vector $x_i-x_0$ into a vector whose $i$th coordinate is $1$ and other are zeroes. Then the parallelotope $P$ transforms to a unit cube $[0,1]^n$ and the question to a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474880/triangulation-n-dimensional-cube-into-exactly-n-simplices) question.